# Installing a perl package

Tags: perl

I am trying to install a Perl package (Config::General). I need it because I have to run a Perl script in which such package is required. I've already tried to install the package by using `perl -MCPAN -e install Config::General`, and apparently it seemed to work!
However, when I run the Perl script, the terminal gives me this error:

> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at
> /Volumes/MYBOOK8TB1/SVDetect/SVDetect_r0.7m/bin/SVDetect line 48

(Yes, line 48 of the perl script is where this package is loaded).
How could I solve such riddle?

Comment: Make sure `@INC` have the mentioned `lib` path.

Comment: And what do you get when you run - `perl -MConfig::General -e 1`?

Comment: Is that the *complete* error message? No other errors listed above it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers.
I solved the problem by running the command

```
sudo cpan
```

in order to enter perl as sudo, and then simply installed the required package by typing

```
install Config::General
```